# display data using search via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using search functionality via ajax in codeigniter... The code is working fine... it properly search the required match but the problem with my code is that it is displaying 2 things in view 1. by default values 2.searched values
But i want is it display default values once when i search then only searched values not default values.
My controller is:

```
public function seller()
{
    $this->load->model('home/Home_model');
    $ser = $this->input->post('search_data');
   if(isset($search))
   {
    $data['h'] = $this->Home_model->search_seller($search);     
    }
    else
    {
    $data['h'] = $this->Home_model->seller();       
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/pages/sellers', $data);    
}
```

My model is

```
      public function seller()  
  {  
     $query = $this->db->get('wc_seller');  
     return $query;  
  } 
    public function search_seller($search)
    {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->like('seller_name', $search);
    $this->db->like('email', $search);
    $query = $this->db->get('wc_seller');
     return $query;
```

}
view is

```
foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
     {  
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo base_url() . "Home/edit_sellers/" . $row->id; ?>" method="POST">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?php echo $i; ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $row->last_modified;?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row-> id; ?>">
                    <td><input type="text" name="seller_name" value="<?php echo $row->seller_name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $row->seller_name;?>" class="form-control"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mobile_no" value="<?php echo $row->mobile_no;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $row->mobile_no;?>" class="form-control"></td>
                    <td>
  </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

my ajax script is

```
       <?php $this->load->view('admin/templates/header'); ?>       

 <div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="graphs">
<h3 class="blank1">All Sellers</h3>
<div class="something">
 <input name="search_data" id="search_data" type="text" onkeyup="ajaxSearch();">
    <div id="suggestions">
        <div id="autoSuggestionsList">  
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="xs tabls tabls1">
     <div class="panel-body1">
         <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
             <thead>

                    <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Registered On</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Full Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile No</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <?php  
    $i = 1; 
     foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
     {  
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo base_url() . "Home/edit_sellers/" . $row->id; ?>" method="POST">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?php echo $i; ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $row->last_modified;?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row-> id; ?>">
                    <td><input type="text" name="seller_name" value="<?php echo $row->seller_name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $row->seller_name;?>" class="form-control"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mobile_no" value="<?php echo $row->mobile_no;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $row->mobile_no;?>" class="form-control"></td>
                    <td>

                    <button type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Update</button>
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="<?php echo base_url() . "Home/delete_seller/" . $row->id; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                    <?php if($row->status == '1' ){
                    $status = 'Deactivate';
                    }
                    else{
                        $status = 'Activate';

                    }
                    ?>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"  onclick="savestatus<?php echo $row->id; ?>(<?php echo $row->id; ?>)"><?php echo $status; ?></button>



                    </td>
                </tr>
    </form>
    <script>
 function savestatus<?php echo $row->id; ?>(row_id){

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/activate_seller/'. $row->id; ?>",
    data:{},       
    success:function( data )
    {
       //$("#"+row_id).html("Deactivate");
       $("#"+row_id).text().trim()==="Activate"?         $("#"+row_id).text("Deactivate"):$("#"+row_id).text("Activate")
    }
   });
    }

    </script>

        <?php 
         $i++;

        }  

          ?> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
     </div>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function ajaxSearch() {
        var input_data = $('#search_data').val();
        if (input_data.length === 0) {
            $('#suggestions').hide();
            //$('.tabls1').show();
        } else {

            var post_data = {
                'search_data': input_data,
                '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/seller/' ?>",
                data: post_data,
                success: function(data) {
                    // return success
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $('#suggestions').show();
                        //$('.tabls1').hide();
                        $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                        $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
       }
   </script>

  <?php $this->load->view('admin/templates/footer'); ?>
```

Comment: Show the full html code (div with id #autoSuggestionsList)

Comment: Give the full html code

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: You got it or what?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your are adding the search result in the same view file. So, try the following things:-

```
Create one new view file someName.php and paste the following code.

    <div class="panel-body1">
        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Registered On</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Mobile No</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php  
$i = 1; 
 foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
 {  
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url() . "Home/edit_sellers/" . $row->id; ?>" method="POST">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $i; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $row->last_modified;?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row-> id; ?>">
                <td><input type="text" name="seller_name" value="<?php echo $row->seller_name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $row->seller_name;?>" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mobile_no" value="<?php echo $row->mobile_no;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $row->mobile_no;?>" class="form-control"></td>
                <td>

                <button type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Update</button>
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="<?php echo base_url() . "Home/delete_seller/" . $row->id; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                <?php if($row->status == '1' ){
                $status = 'Deactivate';
                }
                else{
                    $status = 'Activate';

                }
                ?>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"  onclick="savestatus<?php echo $row->id; ?>(<?php echo $row->id; ?>)"><?php echo $status; ?></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

change your default view file like this:-

```
<?php $this->load->view('admin/templates/header'); ?>       

<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="graphs">
<h3 class="blank1">All Sellers</h3>
<div class="something">
<input name="search_data" id="search_data" type="text" onkeyup="ajaxSearch();">
</div>
<div class="xs tabls tabls1" id="suggestions">
 <div class="panel-body1">
     <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
         <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Registered On</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Mobile No</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php  
$i = 1; 
 foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
 {  
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url() . "Home/edit_sellers/" . $row->id; ?>" method="POST">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $i; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $row->last_modified;?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row-> id; ?>">
                <td><input type="text" name="seller_name" value="<?php echo $row->seller_name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $row->seller_name;?>" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mobile_no" value="<?php echo $row->mobile_no;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $row->mobile_no;?>" class="form-control"></td>
                <td>

                <button type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Update</button>
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="<?php echo base_url() . "Home/delete_seller/" . $row->id; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                <?php if($row->status == '1' ){
                $status = 'Deactivate';
                }
                else{
                    $status = 'Activate';

                }
                ?>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"  onclick="savestatus<?php echo $row->id; ?>(<?php echo $row->id; ?>)"><?php echo $status; ?></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
</form>
<script>
function savestatus<?php echo $row->id; ?>(row_id){

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/activate_seller/'. $row->id; ?>",
data:{},       
success:function( data )
{
   //$("#"+row_id).html("Deactivate");
   $("#"+row_id).text().trim()==="Activate"?         $("#"+row_id).text("Deactivate"):$("#"+row_id).text("Activate")
}
});
}

</script>

    <?php 
     $i++;

    }  

      ?> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
 </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ajaxSearch() {
    var input_data = $('#search_data').val();
    if (input_data.length === 0) {
        $('#suggestions').hide();
        //$('.tabls1').show();
    } else {

        var post_data = {
            'search_data': input_data,
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/seller/' ?>",
            data: post_data,
            success: function(data) {
                // return success
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    //$('.tabls1').hide();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            }
        });

    }
   }
</script>
<?php $this->load->view('admin/templates/footer'); ?>
```

In controller

```
public function seller()
{
$this->load->model('home/Home_model');
$ser = $this->input->post('search_data');
if(isset($search))
{
    $data['h'] = $this->Home_model->search_seller($search);     
    $this->load->view('admin/pages/someName', $data); 
}
else
{
    $data['h'] = $this->Home_model->seller();       
    $this->load->view('admin/pages/sellers', $data); 
}
```

}